# Optimal thumbnail size vs display size when creating images with PHP GD library

Tags: php

When creating thumbnails with PHP GD library, should I create a thumbnail for every specific display size or should I create it a little bit larger and then let the browser scale it down for flexibility?

I have seen a couple of sites and they display thumbnails of sizes like:

> github
>
> ```
>   230x230         70x70       100x100         40x40       48x48       16x16x      20x20
> ```
>
> stack overflow
>
> ```
>   32x32
> ```
>
> quora
>
> ```
>   32x32       40x40
> ```

Do they create a thumbnail for each size? Or do they for example have 1 thumbnail at 48x48 and then use that thumbnail to display at 42x42, 40x40, 32x32 ?

How far can I stretch it before things looks really bad in that case? I suppose there is no point in displaying a 230x230 image at 70x70, in that situation then it might be better to create another thumbnail at that specific size at 70x70, or something a bit larger like 100x100 for flexibility. Or is this a bad idea?

How do websites do these things? Are they creating thumbnails that are a bit larger than display size or exact size and how much larger if it is the case? What are some good practices on this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that this deppends on your needs. You can also write a function taht creates the thumb on the first call for it. This one I used to create 101x101px thumbs on the first call.

```
function getThumb($filename) {
    if(file_exists('uploads/'.$filename)) {
        if(file_exists('uploads/thumbs/'.$filename)) {
            return 'uploads/thumbs/'.$filename;
        } else {
            require_once('php/create_square_image.php');
            create_square_image('uploads/'.$filename, 'uploads/thumbs/'.$filename, 101);
            if(file_exists('uploads/thumbs/'.$filename)) {
                return 'uploads/thumbs/'.$filename;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The required file (create_square_image.php) can be found here: https://github.com/danghoangthien/MediaGurusApp/blob/master/htinmotion/image_handle/create_square_image.php

Generally I wouldn't create a new thumb if the difference is not bigger than 50px.